# generate testng xml file with groups,define and include tags programatically

Tags: testng

I want to generate following testng xml file programatically using java.

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <parameter name="test-parameter1" value="hi1"/>
  <parameter name="test-parameter2" value="hi2"/>
  <test name="Test">
    <groups>
      <define name="FunctionalTest">
        <include name="RegressionTest"/>
        <include name="SmokeTest"/>    
      </define>
      <define name="all">
        <include name="FunctionalTest"/>
        <include name="LongTimeTakingTest"/>
      </define>
      <run>
        <include name="FunctionalTest"/>
        <exclude name="LongTimeTakingTest"/>
        <exclude name="NotWorkingTests"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rightster.test.AppTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Especially looking for this part code:

```
<groups>
      <define name="FunctionalTest">
        <include name="RegressionTest"/>
        <include name="SmokeTest"/>    
      </define>
```

in Java:

```
    XmlGroups groups = new XmlGroups();
    XmlDefine define1 = new XmlDefine();
    define1.setName("FunctionalTest");
```

`XmlDefine` doesn't have any method to set Include.
How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `onElement(string)` method will add an include element to the `define`. Not very obvious is it. I looked at the code.

Comment: Thanks bob, for the answer. But this doesn't work. Anyways I got it.   Thanks @Bob, For the answers. I already got it.                    XmlTest test = new XmlTest();      
test.setName("Test");                                               List<String> ingrp = new ArrayList<String>();
ingrp.add("FunctionalTest");                                        test.addMetaGroup("IntegrationTest",ingrp);                         <groups>
      <define name="IntegrationTest">
        <include name="FunctionalTest"/>
      </define>